FastAPI: обработка запросов по всем путям одинаково
Задача: есть сервис, для работы которого необходим reverse-proxy.
Для реализации этого reverse-proxy выбран fast-api. В логике этого прокси не должно быть никакой работы с путями, он просто должен принять запрос, добавить к нему заголовок отправить его через requests в другое место, и полученый там ответ вернуть.
на примере гет запроса: если пользователь обратится на путь /, то тогда считаем, что сервис отработал верно, однако если пользователь обратится, скажем на /catalog1/ то выдаст 404 (а специфика задачи именно в том, что я не знаю ничего о том, какие каталоги могут появиться, нужно переадресовать по пути, что указал пользователь)
@app.get('/')
def read_users():
    return [{"name": "Rick"}, {"name": "Morty"}]

Подскажите способ как можно сделать, чтобы одно и то же действие делалось вообще по любому пути.

Но зачем fastapi, если есть nginx, который буквально создан для этого?

@app.get("/{rel_path:path}")
async def get_handle(rel_path: str):
    print(rel_path)
    #rel_path - строковая переменная с путем
    ...
    return response


пожалуйста, постарайтесь оставлять чуть более развёрнутые ответы. дополнить ответ можно, нажав [edit]
